# Updating a many-to-many relationship neither entirely code nor database first

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-database-first

I seem to be struggling with a combination of naming conventions and understanding.

I have inherited a database and am building a MVC site that I was unable to get the "database-first" workflow to play nicely. In the end I manually constructed my context classes and have been working away happily.

I am now in a situation where I am unable to add an entity with a relationship to several other existing entities (the many-to-many).

My database looks (simplified for this question) like this:

```
ListItem      Option       OptionListItems
======        ======       ===============
Id            Id           ListItem_Id
Name          Name         Option_Id
```

My context contains a property that allows me to get all of my ListItems:

```
public virtual DbSet<ListItem> ListItems { get; set; }
```

And if I use some LINQ, I do something like the following, and the items are returned and the many-to-many relationship is satisfied and I get a list of `Option` within my `ListItem`:

```
 var item = _context.ListItems
 .Where(p => p.Id == id)
 .Include(p => p.Options)
 .SingleOrDefault();
```

In fact, I had to construct the cross-reference table in the database manually which I did when I tried to run the above query and the exception I got told me I had no object called `dbo.OptionListItems`. So I assumed we were all good.

Now I need to create a new `ListItem` and link it to one or more *existing* `Option` and I'm at a loss.

Once I've created my new `ListItem` in isolation, and attempt to call `listItem.Options.Add(...)` it fails, but I also get the exact same exception if I try to get a reference to a particular `Option` and try to do `option.ListItems.Add(...)`.

The error is kind of amusing and is the opposite table name to what I have:

```
 {"Invalid object name 'dbo.ListItemOptions'."}
```

I suspect that it goes against the grain of EF to build a type and a property on my context to directly access the cross reference table like this:

```
 public virtual DbSet<OptionListItem> OptionListItems { get; set; }
```

But I'm completely baffled by the pattern to create new relationships.

Comment: Not sure how you tore out the DB first stuff, but in Code First if you need to control the many-to-many you will need fluent map code like [this](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) (near the bottom).

Comment: Yeah, it's a weird situation. I had a DB and some manually created POCOs, so on top of that I've been adding bits to both sides manually rather than relying on scaffolding or migrations.

Before I try to create the mapping (I saw that post but wasn't sure it was the best approach), what's the sensible pattern to use? Am I right in Taking my `ListItem` and `.Add`ing to the Options collection  - and therefore with the mapping it should work?

Answer (score 0):

We have this (many-to-many) working declaratively. Pseudocode:

```
public class ListItem   
{

    public ListItem()
    {
        this.RelatedOptions = new HashSet<OptionListItems>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<OptionListItems> RelatedOptions {get; set;}
}

public class Option
{
    public Ortion()
    {
        this.RelatedItems = new HashSet<OptionListItems>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    public virtual ICollection<OptionListItems> RelatedItems {get; set;}
}


public class OptionListItems
{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}

    [Column("ListItemId", Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("ParentListItem")]
    public int ListItemId {get; set;}

    [Column("OptionId", Order = 2)]
    [ForeignKey("ParentOption")]
    public int OptionId {get; set;}

    public virtual ListItem ParentListItem {get; set;}
    public virtual Option ParentOption {get; set;}
}
```

This should create full relationship declaratively

Comment: Thanks - I already had a very similar model, but this post at least helped me validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Credit goes to Steve Greene for pointing me in the right direction.
The table I had was created by convention and worked when I queried `WorkItem` with `.Include(p => p.Options)` however the convention seems to break down if you try to do an update. I'm unsure why, but the construction of the mapping table seems to be `<Entity1>+<Entity2>+s` when querying, but `<Entity2>+<Entity1>+s` when updating...

The good news, by using fluentAPI, I've created a specific mapping between the entities and forced the cross reference table and both querying and updating works!

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<ListItem>()
            .HasMany<Option>(s => s.Options)
            .WithMany(c => c.ListItems)
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("ListItem_Id");
                cs.MapRightKey("Option_Id");
                cs.ToTable("OptionListItems");
            });
    }
```